# Rock Paper Scissor game

Tags: java, methods

why do i get an error in the main method for isValidChoice and determineWinner? 
i want call the return statements from other methods in the program.
the program runs like this generate computerChoice then userChoice, userChoice is validated and last method determines winner. need help in main method wording

```
   public static String computerChoice() 
   {  
         return comp;
   }
    public static String userChoice()
   {

      return userLower;

   }


   public static boolean isValidChoice(String userLower) 
   {

   }
   public static void determineWinner(String userLower, String comp) 
   {


   }
    public static void main(String[] args)
   {

      computerChoice();
      userChoice();

      isValidChoice(String userLower);
      determineWinner(String userLower, String comp);

   }
}
```

Comment: Your method expect a return value (a boolean) and you return nothing. `isValidChoice(String userLower);` and `determineWinner(String userLower, String comp);` are not a valid statements. You should read this : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your syntax is wrong:

```
String comp = computerChoice();
String userLower = userChoice();
isValidChoice(userLower);
determineWinner(userLower, comp);
```

Also, you need to return `boolean` value in `isValidChoice` method.

Answer (score 0):

In the `determineWinner` function you need to calculate somehow who has won the game and then you can return this value in your main.

```
public static String computerChoice() 
{  
   return comp;
}
 public static String userChoice()
{
   return userLower;
}
public static String determineWinner(String userLower, String comp) 
{
   String winner = "";      //calculate winner somehow , examle=> ((int)userLower > (int)comp))
   return winner;
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  String comp = computerChoice();
  String userLower = userChoice();
  String winner = determineWinner(userLower, comp);
}
```